# Compare 2 strings in C

Tags: c

I'm testing a small program which basically compares whether 2 input strings are identical (as strcmp does). However I keep getting result saying 2 strings are different no matter what. If someone could spot out some mistakes I'd appreciate

```
int comp(char str1[], char str2[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while (str1[i] == str2[i]) {
        if (str1[i] == '\0' || str2[i] == '\0')
            break;
        i++;
    }
    if (str1[i] == '\0' && str2[i] == '\0')
        return 0;
    else
        return -1;
}


int main(int argc, char * * argv) {
    int cmp;
    char str1[1000], str2[1000];
    cmp = comp(str1, str2);
    if (cmp == 0)
        printf("The two strings are identical.\n");
    else
        printf("The two strings are different.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The contents of the arrays `str1[1000], str2[1000]` are never set.  We cannot even be sure they have a null character termination.

Comment: You seem to return `-1` for `false`, `0` for `true`. For compatibility with the standard: **do not**! Use the standard boolean values: `0` for `false, `1` for `true`.

Comment: *Always* properly initialise variables *before* reading them.

Comment: @Olaf: "*For compatibility with the standard ...*": Which Standard? Most libc functions indicate an "error" exactly as the OP does. Also the standard `strcmp()` returns `0` on equal.

Comment: @alk: The C11 standard. Comparison operators yield `(int)0` resp. `(int)1`. `comp` is apparently `strequal`. `strcmp` returns a ternary result, so this is a bad reference. In general one should use "speaking" names: `if ( strequal(...) )` is better than `if ( !strcomp(...) )`.

Comment: You don't have two strings to compare *yet*. All you have is a couple of sizable `char` arrays with indeterminate content. So what happens when you do something like "char str1[] = "string", str2[] = "string";`

Comment: @Olaf: `strequal()` is part of C11?

Comment: @alk: Sorry I did not express clearly: `comp` **should actually be called** `strequal` or similar. The last should have been `if ( !comp(...) )`.

Comment: Note: should you want your code to return a +,0,- value like `strcmp()`, recommend after the while loop: `return (str1[i] > str2[i]) - (str1[i] < str2[i])`

Comment: Simplification: `while (str1[i] == str2[i]) { if (str1[i] == '\0') break; i++; }`.  The `|| str2[i] == '\0'` will never be true.

Comment: Your question indicates that two parameter will be passed in from the command line.  So, 1) check argc to assure there are two parameters, if not printf a 'usage' statement.  2) eliminate the local buffers, they are not needed.  when calling comp() pass parameters argv[1] and argv[2]

Comment: when posting code with a runtime problem, please post code that actually cleanly compiles.   The posted code is missing the needed #include header statements.  So does not compile

Answer (score 8):

Your function [works just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb89de7a8e5761f3). The only problem is that your two character arrays are not initialized and that causes Undefined Behavior.

Comment: To give a bit more background information here -- when your code is run, the >= 2000 bytes for `str1` and `str2` are going to be allocated on the stack; which means that the stack pointer will be decremented by >= 2000 bytes, and the pointer to each variable will be stored in two registers (one for `str1`, one for `str2`). Because you don't actually initialize them, *whatever is stored in those >= 2000 bytes on the stack* are technically the "values" in the arrays. What's there? Who knows, it's all just a black box of random bytes until you tell the process to store something in memory.

Comment: Thanks. I want to compare 2 input strings from users that's why I left it uninitialized. I'd want to do something like `./a.out equal equal` to test it out should I do a     `scanf("%s %s", str1, str2);` ?

Comment: "*.. should I do*" better `scanf(%999s %999s, str1, str2);`, to avoid overflowing the buffers by the user's input, yes.

Comment: I tried that and apparently it seems to stuck in an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

here is one implementation, using the command line parameters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int comp(char str1[], char str2[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while (str1[i] == str2[i])
    {
        if (str1[i] == '\0' || str2[i] == '\0')
            break;
        i++;
    }

    if (str1[i] == '\0' && str2[i] == '\0')
        return 0;
    else
        return -1;
}


int main(int argc, char * * argv)
{
    if( 3 != argc )
    {
        printf( "USAGE: %s, firstString secondString\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // implied else, correct number of parameters

    if ( !comp( argv[1], argv[2]) )
        printf("The two strings are identical.\n");
    else
        printf("The two strings are different.\n");
    return 0;
}
```